# Robotic simulator with haptic, proprioceptive, force/torque, joint sensors

Tags: simulator, robotics

I am looking for a robotic arm simulator or a humanoid simulator which has haptic, proprioceptive, force/torque, joint sensors or even more sensors in the arm. Is there any free option?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of free robotics simulators out there.  This question lists a lot of them: [Robotics Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533321/robotics-simulator).

But from what i think you want, you probably want a simulator with a physics engine back-end like Gazebo or Microsoft Robotics Studio.  For arms / grasping, i will also mention GraspIt! http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cmatei/graspit/ and OpenRAVE http://openrave.org/.  Although i am not sure OpenRAVE includes physics.

I am not sure what kind of haptics you are interested in, but i doubt these simulators are accurate enough to simulate surface textures.  i think you will find that these simulators are pretty crude.  I'd say that all the simulators that allow to to build and control joints will therefore allow you to measure joint torques and angles giving you proprioception.  Some of these simulators will allow you to create and add custom sensors to the arms.